# Magento 2: Changing default minimum length of customer password from admin not working. (Seems like a bug)

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.1.5, bug

I have changed the default minimum length of password from admin side but still I am unable to save customer from front end.The default length is being taken from some core constant apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for this.
The file where the constant is declared is

CONSTANT that overrides the admin config:

```
const MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;
```

File path:

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Password.php

Made my own file here:

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Password.php

here is my file code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

/**
 * Customer password attribute backend
 */
class Password extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\Password
{
    /**
     * Min password length
     */
    const MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 5;

    /**
     * Magento string lib
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils
     */
    protected $string;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string)
    {
        $this->string = $string;
    }

    /**
     * Special processing before attribute save:
     * a) check some rules for password
     * b) transform temporary attribute 'password' into real attribute 'password_hash'
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $password = $object->getPassword();

        $length = $this->string->strlen($password);
        if ($length > 0) {
            if ($length < self::MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('Please enter a password with at least %1 characters.', self::MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
                );
            }

            if (trim($password) !== $password) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('The password can not begin or end with a space.'));
            }

            $object->setPasswordHash($object->hashPassword($password));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate($object)
    {
        $password = $object->getPassword();
        if ($password && $password === $object->getPasswordConfirm()) {
            return true;
        }

        return parent::validate($object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is you Magento version?

Did you to clean the cache after your configuration change?

> bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: yes I cleared cache after configuration save. I wanted to save number less than the 6, it saved on admin, but still when customer registered with giving password less than this constant `const MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;`, it did not allow. My version is EE Magento ver. 2.1.5

Comment: Strange, I tried with Magento EE  2.1.4 with a minimum password length at 5 and it works.